# Expanding specific sections of a pivot table in Excel via VBA and/or jumping to original spot

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

> I have a pivot table segmented by years, quarters and months. If I try
> to expand a quarter for 2015, however, the corresponding quarter in
> all other years are shown as well. How can I expand only one quarter
> for one year?
>
> - https://superuser.com/questions/1049881/expanding-specific-sections-of-a-pivot-table-in-excel

This question got no answer there, but that wasn't a programming forum. I have a similar question. Is there a VBA solution?

Alternatively, is there a VBA code to "catch" expansion clicks and then jump into the original cell on which plus was clicked?

[image: Years and months]

Sample code (I want this true just for *2016*):

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Month").PivotItems("3").ShowDetail = True
```

| Year | Month | Text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2015 | 1 | Dummy1 |
| 2015 | 2 | Dummy1 |
| 2015 | 3 | Dummy1 |
| 2015 | 4 | Dummy1 |
| 2015 | 5 | Dummy1 |
| 2016 | 1 | Dummy1 |
| 2016 | 2 | Dummy1 |
| 2016 | 3 | Dummy1 |
| 2016 | 4 | Dummy1 |
| 2016 | 5 | Dummy1 |
| 2017 | 1 | Dummy1 |
| 2017 | 2 | Dummy1 |
| 2017 | 3 | Dummy1 |
| 2017 | 4 | Dummy1 |
| 2017 | 5 | Dummy1 |
| 2015 | 1 | Dummy2 |
| 2015 | 2 | Dummy2 |
| 2015 | 3 | Dummy2 |
| 2015 | 4 | Dummy2 |
| 2015 | 5 | Dummy2 |
| 2016 | 1 | Dummy2 |
| 2016 | 2 | Dummy2 |
| 2016 | 3 | Dummy2 |
| 2016 | 4 | Dummy2 |
| 2016 | 5 | Dummy2 |
| 2017 | 1 | Dummy2 |
| 2017 | 2 | Dummy2 |
| 2017 | 3 | Dummy2 |
| 2017 | 4 | Dummy2 |
| 2017 | 5 | Dummy2 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this? This will be a good starting point for you, you'll have to create an IF THEN for each month

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

    If (ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Month").PivotItems("3").ShowDetail) Then
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Month").PivotItems("3").ShowDetail = False
        Sheets(2).Activate
        '''' Change filter options here? or have a cell selected?
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think your answer makes sure every other month than 3 gets closed when you choose 3. But that's not what I asked. I asked how to expand only 3/2016 and not 3 of other years.

Comment: Nope, not at all... I tested it with your spread sheet as well, basically when you click the 3 from 2016 (the one you have as a red square) it will close it again and activate the second sheet. After the second sheet is activated, the next step could be applying filters to that page (ie. show only 2016 and month 3)

Comment: Do you mean the second sheet should contain the raw data, so you recommend to filter the raw data automatically based on Pivot table choices? But it's the pivot table that I want filtered. I guess another way is to the second part of your comment right in the Pivot  itself, but I'm not sure how to determine the parent.